# How do I Remove particular dublicate characters from string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a mail project and it has reply function to particular email. There are pre-written things in reply email like `Re: ${Subject of the email}`

There is `Re:`  that repeats after 2nd reply so i wrote this in my function in order to remove it:

```
subject = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value;

  if (subject.includes("Re: ")){
              subject = subject.replace("Re: ", "");
          }
```

How do i make this part of code work only for dublicates? Like `Re: Re:`  (removing 2nd `Re:` )

Now it works even on first `Re:`  and just removing it.

How can i implement it?

Comment: Isn't this what you want?  `if (subject.includes("Re: Re:")){subject=subject.replace("Re: Re:", "Re:");}`

Comment: @wonderflame But replace the `if` with a `while` :)

Comment: I thought that it can only be two Re at most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regexp to replace any number of repeated `Re:`s with any number of spaces after them with a single `Re:` :

```
var subject = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value;
subject = subject.replace(/^(Re:\s+)+/g, 'Re: ');
```

You can add the `i` flag for case insensitivity too (i.e. `/gi` instead of `/g`).

Comment: Thank you, i liked it more than previous answers in comments! It solved my problem as well

Comment: Note the use of  /g  for this RegEx, which means that any number of "RE: " will be replaced. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @MikeB It has the `^` anchor, so no, not really.

Comment: @MikeB this is exactly what i wanted just had no idea how to say it right :)

Comment: @AKX  Good point about the  /g, however  the  + following the brackets will do much the same thing.  And if it wasn't intended, why is it there?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace doubles with singles

```js
console.log(tidy("foo"));
console.log(tidy("Re: foo"));
console.log(tidy("Re: Re: foo"));
console.log(tidy("Re: Re: Re: foo"));


function tidy(input){
  while(input.indexOf("Re: Re: ")>-1){
   input = input.replaceAll("Re: Re: ", "Re: ");
  }
  return input;
}
```